# If $f_n \to f$ almost uniformly, then $f_n \to f$ a.e. in measure

Tags: real-analysis

This is my homework, I have seen the proof of Egoroff theorem, and this problem is the counter direction of Egoroff theorem. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost uniformly. Then for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a measurable set $E_m$ such that $m(E_m)<\frac{1}{m}$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E\backslash E_m$.

Let $\alpha>0$. Then we have the following estimate
\begin{align}
&m\{x \in E : |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} \\
&= m\{ x \in E_m : |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq\alpha\} + m\{x \in E\backslash E_m : |f(x) -f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} \\
&\leq\  m(E_m) + m\{x \in E\backslash E_m : |f(x) -f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} \\
&\leq\ \frac{1}{m}+ m\{x \in E\backslash E_m : |f(x) -f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\}.
\end{align}

Fix $\epsilon>0$. **The task is to find a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have**
\begin{align}
m\{x \in E : |f(x) - f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} <\epsilon . 
\end{align}

**Step 1:** Choose $N_1 > 1/\epsilon$ which means $m^{-1}<\epsilon$ whenever $m \geq N_1$. Next, **fix  $m\geq N_1$** (we will use this $m$ later), then we know that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E\backslash E_m$, i.e. there exists $N_2$ such that for all $n \geq N_2$ we have
\begin{align}
|f(x) -f_n(x) | <\alpha \ \ \forall \ x \in E\backslash E_m.
\end{align}

**Step 2**:  Let us choose $N=  N_2$. Then by the above estimate, we see that for all $n \geq N$ we have
\begin{align}
m\{x \in E : |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} \leq \frac{1}{m} +m\{x\in E\backslash E_m \mid |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} = \frac{1}{m} <\epsilon.
\end{align}

**Note we have use the following fact**: By step 1, we see the set $\{x\in E\backslash E_m \mid |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\}$ is actually empty when $n\geq N$ which mean 
\begin{align}
m\{x\in E\backslash E_m \mid |f(x)-f_n(x)| \geq \alpha\} =0.
\end{align}

Comment: May I ask how do we know 1/m+m{x∈E∖Em:|f(x)−fn(x)|≥α}=1/m    on step 2???

Comment: Read the Note in the last paragraph.

Comment: How do we know {x∈E∖Em∣|f(x)−fn(x)|≥α} is actually empty when n≥N?

Comment: Please read step 1.

Comment: Because n>=N2 we have  |f(x)−fn(x)|<α, so   {x∈E∖Em∣|f(x)−fn(x)|≥α} empty?

Comment: I GOT IT!!!  Your prove is very very detailed. Thank you so much!